# how can I add react component to DOM dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, components

I want to add React component to DOM. Next, I need to remove (hide) that. Then, I want to add (show) again that with all data entried.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

}
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value })
}
render() {
    return <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} name="name" />
}
```

in parent Component:

```
<div>
     {this.state.show && < MyComponent />}
     <button onClick={() => { this.setState({ show: !this.state.show }) }} >change</button>
</div>
```

Comment: this.setState(
       (prevState,props)=>{
           return {show : !prevState. show};
        }
    );

Answer (score 0):

There will be few steps here...

1. Declare a state as const [show,setShow] = useState()
2. Now render the DOM element conditionally, like

show ? element1 : element2

Comment: I have added my code to this post, But That don't Work .please see that.

Comment: Please share your parent component code too. The show state has problems in it logically.

Comment: const Parent = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      {show && <MyComponent />}
      <button onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>change</button>
    </div>
  );
};

Comment: It seems fair to me, what;s the behavior of code?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to use style.
We can send the status as a parameter to the component else component will be load again and data'll be clear